# Enable Azure AD SSO on Web Server which has no internet connection

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I implement my ASP.Net Web Application SSO with Azure AD. Everything work fine my testing server which has an internet connection.
My customer policy does not allow internet connection on their server and the SSO failed when validate the token from the Microsoft after user authenticated. The error is "IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: [PII is Hidden]".
I add the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` to my Startup.cs class, the error more detail: "IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANTID/.well-known/openid-configuration'".

My question is: I will request my customer open their firewall to allow only [login.mirosoftonline.com](https://login.mirosoftonline.com). Does it enough? Does it need to allow another requests? And what are another requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges#microsoft-365-common-and-office-online

I believe category 56 is for identity and authentication, whether you need them all, I'm not sure, but Microsoft seems to think so?

56  Allow
Required    Yes     *.msappproxy.net, *.msftidentity.com, *.msidentity.com, account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com, accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net, adminwebservice.microsoftonline.com, api.passwordreset.microsoftonline.com, autologon.microsoftazuread-sso.com, becws.microsoftonline.com, clientconfig.microsoftonline-p.net, companymanager.microsoftonline.com, device.login.microsoftonline.com, graph.microsoft.com, graph.windows.net, login.microsoft.com, login.microsoftonline.com, login.microsoftonline-p.com, login.windows.net, logincert.microsoftonline.com, loginex.microsoftonline.com, login-us.microsoftonline.com, nexus.microsoftonline-p.com, passwordreset.microsoftonline.com, provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com
20.190.128.0/18, 40.126.0.0/18, 2603:1006:2000::/48, 2603:1007:200::/48, 2603:1016:1400::/48, 2603:1017::/48, 2603:1026:3000::/48, 2603:1027:1::/48, 2603:1036:3000::/48, 2603:1037:1::/48, 2603:1046:2000::/48, 2603:1047:1::/48, 2603:1056:2000::/48, 2603:1057:2::/48

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will discuss with my customer.

Comment: Does this answer mean internet is required on the server for SSO to work on the client machines?